# Is returning an int an atomic operation in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

```
// is this atomic? 
public int size() {
    return count;
}
```

Note that count can be changed by other methods in other threads.

I know integer reads and writes are atomic, but I am not sure about return.

What got me alarmed is that for some reason [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue.size%28%29) locks it's size() method.

Comment: While I cannot answer your question, I believe that returns are actually copies of values. If the read/write itself is atomic, your return value is perfectly safe, because it 'reads' the value into the copy buffer and returns that copy.

Comment: Integer *increments* are not atomic, and `count` may be incremented in another thread.

Comment: have you declared count `volatile`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reads and writes to primitive `int` are atomic as you already know. Returning is basically reading and placing in some other place in memory. Since reading is atomic, no race condition will occur. You either return previous or next value of `int`.

Using `lock` in `ArrayBlockingQueue` might be due to visibility reasons. `count` variable is not `volatile` so if the queue was modified in the meantime, without some sort of locking you are not guaranteed to see the *most recent* value of `count`. But since read and writes are atomic, at least you'll never see youngest 16 bits of old value and oldest 16 bits of new value.

Comment: +1 for mentioning visibility, which is the important point here

Comment: Note that reads and writes of longs and doubles are not atomic, as long as the field is not declared volatile.

Comment: **most recent value** of course, can't believe I did not think of that.

Comment: What are *visiblity reasons*?

Comment: @Raffaele: in simple words, sometimes when one thread modifies variable this change isn't immediately (or ever) visible by other threads. See: http://java.dzone.com/articles/multithreading-and-java-memory

Answer (score 0):

Reading primitives ( except long and double) is atomic.

But suppose there is a synchronized method which is modifying value of the count ; in such case your read may or may not be atomic.

```
 synchronized void changeCount(){
     //modifying value of count
 }
```

So in that case you should also synchronized your read method or minimum declare count as volatile. This will ensure that read is also atomic and the correct and **consistent** value is returned